# filter 2d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I need some help to build a function that can filter the 'data' array, according to the data that is in the 'search' array

```js
data = [
    ['a1','1','teste1','teste9'],
    ['a1','2','teste2','teste10'],
    ['a2','1','teste3','teste11'],
    ['a2','1','teste4','teste12'],
    ['a2','1','teste5','teste13'],
    ['a3','1','teste6','teste14'],
    ['a3','1','teste7','teste15'],
    ['a4','1','teste8','teste16']
]

search = [
    ['a1','AAAA'],
    ['a4','DDDD']
]
```

the result:

```js
data = [
    ['a1','1','teste1','teste9'],
    ['a1','2','teste2','teste10'],
    ['a4','1','teste8','teste16']
]
```

Comment: Well, you should at least tell us what the filtering criteria are. Should the filtering return all arrays in `data` where the first element is equal to the first element in any array in `search`? Should the filtering return all arrays in `data` that contain an element (no matter which one) equal to the first element in any array in `search`? Should the filtering return all arrays in `data` that contain an element (no matter which one) equal to another element (no matter which) in any array in `search`? Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#filter` in conjunction with `Array#some`.

```js
const data = [
    ['a1','1','teste1','teste9'],
    ['a1','2','teste2','teste10'],
    ['a2','1','teste3','teste11'],
    ['a2','1','teste4','teste12'],
    ['a2','1','teste5','teste13'],
    ['a3','1','teste6','teste14'],
    ['a3','1','teste7','teste15'],
    ['a4','1','teste8','teste16']
],
search = [
    ['a1','AAAA'],
    ['a4','DDDD']
];
const res = data.filter(arr => arr.some(x => search.some(y => y.includes(x))));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it filters out the required array by applying filter and matching first element with data

```
const result = data.filter(e=>search.some(a=>e[0]==a[0]));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try looping through both arrays and return matched results.

```js
function filterArray(dataArr, filterArr) {
  let res = []
  for (const i in dataArr) {
    for (const j in filterArr) {
      if (dataArr[i][0] === filterArr[j][0]) {
        res.push(dataArr[i])
      }
    }
  }
  return res
}

console.log(filterArray(data, search))
```

Comment: Just need to leave a comment here in order to unlock "Comment everywhere"